# Split a range of numbers in equal parts SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query to split the range of numbers in parts. For ex: i have range of 200 numbers and i have to group the numbers to 95 But Result is coming in reverse order.I Have attached expected result

```
declare @MinValue bigint = 1 
declare @MaxValue bigint = 200;

declare @RowsPerGroup bigint =95
declare @RowsPerGroup1 bigint =(@RowsPerGroup-1)
;with src(val,rm) as (
select @MaxValue, (@MaxValue - @RowsPerGroup1) union all
select rm-1, case when rm-1 > @MinValue + @RowsPerGroup1 then rm-1 - @RowsPerGroup1 else @MinValue end from src where rm-1 >= @MinValue
)
select rm as 'Start', val  as 'End',[Difference]=(val-rm)+1 from src order by rm asc
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Current Result:

```
Start   End Difference
1       10  10
11     105  95
106    200  95
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Pls let me know where am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My variant:

```
DECLARE
  @MinValue bigint = 1,
  @MaxValue bigint = 200,
  @RowsPerGroup bigint = 95 -- 300

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT @MinValue [Start],IIF(@RowsPerGroup>@MaxValue,@MaxValue,@RowsPerGroup) [End]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT [End]+1,IIF([End]+@RowsPerGroup>@MaxValue,@MaxValue,[End]+@RowsPerGroup)
  FROM cte
  WHERE [End]<@MaxValue
)
SELECT [Start],[End],[End]-[Start]+1 [Difference]
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the reason in the first line of the common table expression:

```
select @MaxValue, (@MaxValue - @RowsPerGroup1)
```

This inserts `(200,106)` intto `src`. The second select then counts down from existing rows. To adapt the CTE, exchange minimums with maximums (including for ranges), invert arithmetic, reverse comparisons and any other related exchanges:

```
    select @MinValue, (@MinValue + @RowsPerGroup1) union all
    select val+1, case
        when val+1 < @MaxValue - @RowsPerGroup1
          then val+1 + @RowsPerGroup1
        else @MaxValue
        end
      from src
      where val+1 <= @MaxValue
```

This particular statement can be simplified in parts:

```
    select @MinValue, (@MinValue + @RowsPerGroup - 1) union all
    select val + 1, case
        when val + @RowsPerGroup < @MaxValue
          then val + @RowsPerGroup
        else @MaxValue
        end
      from src
      where val < @MaxValue
```